# How to discretize a line into segments aligned to an arbitrary grid

Tags: geometry, line, trace, discretization

Consider:
[image]
the aim is to discretize an arbitrary line-segment, red line, into a set of connected line-segments aligned on an arbitrary grid (blue line segments). Here only two simple forms of grid i.e., square and rotated square grids are shown.
The red line can be in any angle and size.
The grid configuration including type and cell size is up to the user choice.
Bresenham's discretization may work for simple cases, but even then there are two obstacles:

1. it is limited to vertically and horizontally aligned grids.
2. it gives pixel (i.e., square block) where line-segments are
   required.

**Important Update:**
Important Update:
We are interested in general solution which works for any grid complexity. 
[image]

A more generalized approach is of interest. Providing pesudo-codes or codes are very appreciated.
This question can also be found [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/70862/how-to-discretise-a-line-into-grid-lines).

Answer (score 0):

In case of rotated rectangular grid:

- apply inverse rotation transform for line segment end points
- use Bresenham without the traditional half pixel offset (to center the pixel block)

  - The algorithm gives horizontal and vertical [or minor axis, major axis] increments
- apply forward rotation transform for line segments

In case of "random" grid I'd suggest using cell-based approach, where each cell is first split into convex (Voronoi regions) if necessary. Eg. hexagonal grid consists already of voronoi regions. Keep list of neighbors of each cell.

- First task is go from starting cell to end cell only through the neighbors of each cell. Luckily in case of convex tessellation, one can pick the cell, whose's center is closer/closest to the target. (Search is over, when no progression is possible).
- Next task is to find a path from the entry point to the exit point in each cell, either CW or CCW. One is shorter.

Figure:

```
a----------b--------------d  
*          |              |  
     A     c       B      |     C
                          e
                          |           x
                          f-----------g
```

Here the endpoints '*' and 'x' are in the boundaries of the cells.
One forms the pattern '*abcbdefgx' and reduces it to '*abdfgx' or even to '*adfgx', as 'b-a' dot 'd-b' (normalized) is zero or at least very close.

Comment: Note that the grid can be very complex, i.e., cells can have any shape. In this case rotation does not help.